# DNS lookup getting Non-existent domain error

Tags: dns, forwarding, nslookup, dig, bind9

I have two mirrored forward DNS server(for simplifying, named f1, f2) which forward some domain request to my authoritative DNS server(also named a1, a2), I added some new domain to my authoritative DNS server, but when I `nslookup` the new domain from f1 or f2, I got Non-existent domain error like the following. If I `nslookup` from a1 or a2, it worked.

```
C:\Users\Liu.D.H>nslookup www.yqsbfiles.ynu.edu.cn
Server:  ynu-public-dns-a.ynu.edu.cn
Address:  113.55.13.51

*** ynu-public-dns-a.ynu.edu.cn can't find www.yqsbfiles.ynu.edu.cn: Non-existent domain
C:\Users\Liu.D.H>
```

I also used `dig` to get more debug info.

```
C:\Users\Liu.D.H>dig www.yqsbfiles.ynu.edu.cn @113.55.13.52

; <<>> DiG 9.10.6 <<>> www.yqsbfiles.ynu.edu.cn @113.55.13.52
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 28130
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;www.yqsbfiles.ynu.edu.cn.      IN      A

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
ynu.edu.cn.             9936    IN      SOA     pridns.ynu.edu.cn. root.pridns.ynu.edu.cn. 2016062301 10800 3600 604800 86400

;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 113.55.13.52#53(113.55.13.52)
;; WHEN: Fri Jun 08 10:44:35 China Standard Time 2018
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 101


C:\Users\Liu.D.H>
```

But the strange thing was that if I did `rndc flush` on one of f1 or f2, then I can request successfully.

```
C:\Users\Liu.D.H>dig www.yqsbfiles.ynu.edu.cn @113.55.13.51

; <<>> DiG 9.10.6 <<>> www.yqsbfiles.ynu.edu.cn @113.55.13.51
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 4168
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 2, AUTHORITY: 2, ADDITIONAL: 5

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;www.yqsbfiles.ynu.edu.cn.      IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
www.yqsbfiles.ynu.edu.cn. 86400 IN      CNAME   lb-http.ynu.edu.cn.
lb-http.ynu.edu.cn.     86393   IN      A       202.203.208.41

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
ynu.edu.cn.             86391   IN      NS      secdns.ynu.edu.cn.
ynu.edu.cn.             86391   IN      NS      pridns.ynu.edu.cn.

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
pridns.ynu.edu.cn.      86396   IN      A       202.203.208.33
pridns.ynu.edu.cn.      86396   IN      AAAA    2001:250:2800:2::33
secdns.ynu.edu.cn.      86391   IN      A       202.203.208.34
secdns.ynu.edu.cn.      86391   IN      AAAA    2001:250:2800:2::34

;; Query time: 2 msec
;; SERVER: 113.55.13.51#53(113.55.13.51)
;; WHEN: Fri Jun 08 10:43:02 China Standard Time 2018
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 221


C:\Users\Liu.D.H>
```

I noticed that this two dig output had something different in `AUTHORITY SECTION`.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to register the Authoritative Domain name server with the domain registrar for your new domain pointing to a1 and a2. After that it will work fine.

Comment: hi,  could you give me more tips. Thanks.